# How to filter elements with same id

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a array like this:

```
    element 1 => [
    #id: "**b26b0d394282a3a2b841137928a0"
    #referencedId: "**b26b0d394282a3a2b841137928a0"
    #label: "test mit variante"
    #quantity: 1
    #type: "product"
    #payload: array:18 [▼
        "parentId" => "**744dc8466b48c255b2ab2"
        "cos" => "**744dc8466b48c255b2ab2"
        "options" => array:2 [▶]
    ]

    ]

    element 2 => [
    [
    #id: "**b26b0d394282a3a2b8343441137928a0"
    #referencedId: "**b26b0d394282a3a2b8343441137928a0"
    #label: "test 2 mit variante"
    #quantity: 1
    #type: "product"
    #payload: array:18 [▼
        "parentId" => "**744dc8466b48c255b2ab2"
        "cos" => "**744dc8466b48c255b2ab2"
        "isCloseout" => false
        "releaseDate" => null
        "tagIds" => null
        "categoryIds" => array:4 [▶]
        "propertyIds" => null
        "optionIds" => array:4 [▶]
        "options" => array:2 [▶]
        "features" => []
    ]
    ]

    element 3 => [
    [
    #id: "**b26b0d394282a3a2b841137928a0"
    #referencedId: "**b26b0d394282a3a2b841137928a0"
    #label: "test 2 mit variante"
    #quantity: 1
    #type: "product"
    #payload: array:18 [▼
        "parentId" => "**744dc8466b48c255b2ab2"
        "cos" => "**744dc8466b48c255b2ab2"
        "isCloseout" => false
        "releaseDate" => null
        "tagIds" => null
        "categoryIds" => array:4 [▶]
        "propertyIds" => null
        "optionIds" => array:5 [▶]
        "options" => array:5 [▶]
        "features" => []
    ]
    ]

    element 4 => [
    [
    #id: "**b5645646"
    #referencedId: "**b5645646"
    #label: "test 2 mit variante"
    #quantity: 1
    #type: "product"
    #payload: array:18 [▼
        "parentId" => "**71114545"
        "cos" => "**71114545"
        "isCloseout" => false
        "releaseDate" => null
        "tagIds" => null
        "categoryIds" => array:4 [▶]
        "propertyIds" => null
        "optionIds" => array:4 [▶]
        "options" => array:3 [▶]
        "features" => []
    ]
    ]

    element 5 => [
    [
    #id: "**b5645634346"
    #referencedId: "**b5645634346"
    #label: "test 2 mit variante"
    #quantity: 1
    #type: "product"
    #payload: array:18 [▼
        "parentId" => "**71114545"
        "cos" => "**71114545"
        "isCloseout" => false
        "releaseDate" => null
        "tagIds" => null
        "categoryIds" => array:4 [▶]
        "propertyIds" => null
        "optionIds" => array:4 [▶]
        "options" => array:3 [▶]
        "features" => []
    ]
    ]
```

I want to somhow filter the elements with the same parentId and show them on the page like this:

**test1 - Size: XL, XS, XXL**

**test2 - Size: XLL, XS, M, XXL**

so far i tried using twig filter like this:

https://symfony.com/blog/twig-adds-filter-map-and-reduce-features

```
   {% block custom_layout_products %}

   {% for lineitem in page.cart.lineItems | filter(lineitem => lineitem.payload.parentId is same as lineitem.payload.parentId) %}

   {{lineitem.label}}

   {% endfor %}

   % endblock %}
```

lineitem.payload.parentId is same as lineitem.payload.parentId will return true and i get the all names.

i also tried using loop.first but still no success:

```
   % for lineitem in page.cart.lineItems %}
          {% if loop.first and lineitem.payload.parentId == lineitem.payload.parentId %}
          {{lineitem.label}}
   {% endif %}
```

does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Okay, so yesterday you've said there also items which don't have an parentId (so those items are the actual main product)? Is this still the case or this is the array you are going to work with?

Comment: Yes these are actual Products, and the array I'm going to work with i have just edited above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234696/discussion-between-darkbee-and-arash-yazdani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you need to display a list of products with their corresponding variants, e.g. T-Shirt Alpha in red and blue.

At this point you have an array that contains all the variants an user put in their cart. So the first thing you need to do is create a new array that only contains the "main" product, e.g. T-Shirt Alpha.

You could do this in `twig` as shown in the snippet below, but preferably you would want to do this in your controller

```html
{% set parents = [] %}
{% for lineItem in page.cart.lineItems %}
    {% set parents = parents|merge({ (lineItem.payload.parentId) : lineItem, }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

So lets say you have the following products in the cart:

- T-Shirt One - red
- T-Shirt Two - blue
- T-Shirt One - green
- T-Shirt One - yellow
- T-Shirt Three - orange

Then parents would only contain:

- T-Shirt One
- T-Shirt Two
- T-Shirt Three

Now you can loop this new (unique) array, which only contains 1 of each of the different "main" products, to display them and their variants (which are still stored in the original array `page.cart.lineItems`)

To do so, you now can use the `parentId` of the "main" product to fetch all the variants.

```html
{% for parent in parents %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Label</td><td>{{ parent.label }}</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Size</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                {% for variant in page.cart.lineItems|filter(v => v.payload.parentId == parent.payload.parentId) %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ variant.size }}</td>
                        <td>{{ variant.quantity }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://fiddle.nette.org/twig/#a0c7d29873)

[image]

---

The main difference in my snippet versus yours is that I use an unique list of "main" products of which I use the `parentId` to narrow down the variants

`page.cart.lineItems|filter(v => v.payload.parentId == parent.payload.parentId) %}`

In the code you've posted you've used the following

`filter(lineitem => lineitem.payload.parentId is same as lineitem.payload.parentId)`

Here you are using the same object to try and narrow the list down. But because you are using the same object, this is actually writing the same as the following:

`filter(lineitem => 1 == 1)`

This will always evaluate as `true`